# Return null values in GROUP BY query

Tags: sql

This only returns results for entries that exist, which makes sense, but I'm trying to get it to display all of the B.[HostName] entries, even if there aren't entries for all of them.  I'd like it to show 0 under the count for those.  I've read about needing to use a LEFT JOIN on some of the tables and changing the COUNT(*) to use a field instead, but whenever I have tried that, it still results in the same data.  Can anyone show me what would need to be changed for this to work the way I mentioned?

EDIT:
To clarify, since the initial answers didn't work:
The count would be coming from this table: [Database].[dbo].[WorkItemHistory] A  -- we want all of the entries of A.[PlatformId]

A.[PlatformId] is a foreign key to C.[Id]
AND C.[EngineId] is a foreign key to B.[Id]

From there, we are getting B.[HostName]

So, all entries for B.[HostName] would be listed in the output and the count would come from the entries in the A.[WorkitemHistory] table.

We are using

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.[HostName], COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM [Database].[dbo].[WorkItemHistory] A, [Database].[dbo].[Engine] B, [Database].[dbo].[Platforms] C 
WHERE A.[PlatformId] = C.[Id]
AND B.[Id] = C.[EngineId]
AND A.[Status] = '30'
AND A.[LastAttemptDateTime] >= CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)
GROUP BY B.[HostName]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Move your filters into the join condition. You're gonna have to use newer join syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Something like this will do it. You just need to left join the other tables to [Database].[dbo].[Engine] since you want all the hostnames.

```
SELECT B.[HostName], 
       COUNT(C.ID) AS Count
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Engine] B
LEFT JOIN [Database].[dbo].[Platforms] C
  ON B.[Id] = C.[EngineId]
LEFT JOIN [Database].[dbo].[WorkItemHistory] A  
  ON A.[PlatformId] = C.[Id]
     AND A.[Status] = '30'
     AND AND A.[LastAttemptDateTime] >= CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)
GROUP BY B.[HostName]     
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Same results as mine

Comment: You can use the field that contains the values you want to count inside the count function. If it is a field that comes from table B or C, you will get the expected result. Check out the updated query for example.

Comment: All of the HostNames are retuned but the counts are incorrect now.

Comment: Which table has the filed you want to use for counting?

Comment: I changed the count to be: COUNT(A.[PlatformId]) and that worked for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `JOIN` with a `RIGHT JOIN B`  like below
to give values of B that doesnt have any common values of B in others.

```
SELECT  B.[HostName], COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM [Database].[dbo].[WorkItemHistory] A 
JOIN [Database].[dbo].[Platforms] C 
On A.[PlatformId] = C.[Id]
RIGHT JOIN [Database].[dbo].[Engine] B
On C.[id]=B.[EngineId]
Where A.[Status] = '30'
AND A.[LastAttemptDateTime] >= CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)
GROUP BY B.[HostName]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Same results as mine

Comment: Did you mean error? Can you check now ive edited